# Remove product title in Display Product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm using WordPress + WooCommerce and I'd like to remove the product title in the display product page. In particular I'd like to show the product thumbnail only.
However, the product title should be visible in the single product page.

Suggestions? Is it possible? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
ul.products h3 
{
    display: none;
}
```

to the style.css on your website should hide the title of the product, but not on the single product page.

Answer (score 1):

According to the latest WooCommerce version, following CSS hide product title in archive page

```
ul.products h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title {
    display: none;
}
```